# Select substring for a given column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the variable 'Date of Birth' with the next form:

```
1988-05-04
```

How can I get the max and min values of this variable?

Also, how can I convert the variable to a categorical variable of group of years. For example:

```
0 = 70 to 74   
1 = 75 to 80   
2 = 81 to 85
```

etc

I can think of several ways to do this:

```
dataset1['DOB'] = dataset1['DOB'].str[:4]
```

```
for i in range(0, len(dataset1)):
    dataset1.iloc[i].DOB = dataset1.iloc[i].Name[:4]
```

The problem that I face is that the column is a `pandas.Series`, and it doesn´t have neither str nor Name attributes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have no `str` accessor because the dtype of DOB is `datetime64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`.

Suppose your dataframe:

```
>>> df
         DOB
0 1988-05-04
1 1978-07-30
2 1970-01-01
3 1984-11-08

# Ensure DOB dtype is datetime64
>>> df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])

# Check dtype
>>> df.dtypes
DOB    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Prepare your bins and cut:

```
bins = range(1970, 2025, 5)
labels = range(len(bins) - 1)

df['CAT'] = pd.cut(df['DOB'].dt.year, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
         DOB CAT
0 1988-05-04   3
1 1978-07-30   1
2 1970-01-01   0
3 1984-11-08   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataset1['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset1['DOB'])
dataset1['year'] = dataset1['DOB'].dt.year
```

first, you convert the series to datetime object and then you can extract the year.